# Access associated records when using custom join on coalesce-d id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, rails-activerecord, coalesce

I have two models in my Rails app, `Organization` and `Warehouse`. Entries in `Warehouse` belong to entries in `Organization` either via `Warehouse.organization_id` ('owned' warehouses) or `Warehouse.delegated_to_organization_id` ('delegated' warehouses).

A use case requires me to go over all warehouses and their 'responsible' organization: The 'delegating' organization if existing, otherwise the 'owning' organization. However, the use cases requires me to have all warehouses grouped by organization and is executed in batches (1), leading me to this approach:

```rb
def organizations
  Organization.joins(warehouse_join)
end

def warehouse_join
  <<~SQL
    INNER JOIN warehouses
    ON coalesce(
      warehouses.delegated_to_organization_id,
      warehouses.organization_id,
      -1
    ) = organizations.id
  SQL
end
```

However, ActiveRecord seemingly ignores the join: `organizations.first.warehouses` always yields `[]`, while executing the query with `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(organizations.to_sql.gsub('"organizations".*', '*')).to_a` shows joined fields from the `warehouses` table.

What  am I doing wrong and how can I make this work?

---

(1) The data volume is too large to read everything into memory, so the actual query is executed in batches (having a `limit` attached).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`organizations.first.warehouses` will only fetch `warehouses` by `organization_id`. Your `warehouse_join` does not affect this relation.

Also, in order to have associated objects available through an individual object of the queried collection without extra DB queries you have to use preloading (eager loading) methods such as `includes`.

For example, if you want to fetch a list of `organizations` with their `warehouses`, you should do that like this:

```
orgs = organizations.includes(:warehouses)

# now you can access `warehouses` of each individual `organization` without extra DB queries
orgs.first.warehouses
orgs.second.warehouses
```

As far as I know it is impossible (or not so easy) in `ActiveRecord` to use `includes` with a custom JOIN condition.

But in your case I wouldn't try to do that, there is another way. Use two separate associations (one for each foreign key):

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Model
  # delegated warehouses         
  has_many :delegated_warehouses, class_name: "Warehouse", 
                                  foreign_key: "delegated_to_organization_id" 
  # owned, but not delegated to any other organization
  has_many :owned_not_delegated_warehouses, -> { where(delegated_to_organization_id: nil) }, 
                                            class_name: "Warehouse", 
                                            foreign_key: organization_id                                  

  def warehouses_under_responsibility
    # do not do like this!!! those associations are for preloading only!
    delegated_warehouses + owned_not_delegated_warehouses # wrong!!!

    # the right way
    Warehouse.where("coalesce(delegated_to_organization_id, organization_id, -1) = ?", id)
  end
end
```

Now you can use the associations to separately preload (eager load) `warehouses` that are under responsibility.

```
orgs = Organization.includes(:delegated_warehouses, :owned_not_delegated_warehouses)

orgs.each do |org|
  # now you can access the associated records separately
  owned_warehouses = org.owned_not_delegated_warehouses
  delegated_warehouses = org.delegated_warehouses

  # or use them all together
  all_warehouses = owned_warehouses + delegated_warehouses
end
```

**Note:**

Those associations should only be used when preloading warehouses, i.e. when there is a large collection of organization and you need to fetch the warehouses they are responsible for.

If you have a single organization and need to fetch the warehouses it is responsible for, you should use another approach, which is shown in the `warehouses_under_responsibility` method.

It is important to understand why we didn't use the same approach when preloading. That is because we can't make `include` work with the custom join condition which is `coalesce(delegated_to_organization_id, organization_id, -1) = organizations.id`

Comment: Thank you for your insightful answer. What I'm missing in your solution is a way to find only the warehouses a certain organization is 'responsible' for – currently you'd have to check `all_warehouses` again to see if this is the case for the given `org`. Do you know an easy 'railsy' way to do this in one step?

Comment: `all_warehouses` is an array of `warehouses` of a single organization. Look carefully at the code. I am looping through all the organizations (`orgs.each do |org|`) and fetching related `warehouses` of each of them individually.

Comment: Yes, but _'related' warehouses_ (`all_warehouses`) is not the same as _warehouses the organization is 'responsible' for_, using the terminology introduced by the question. I don't know whether some of the `owned_warehouses` are delegated to other organizations, making them 'responsible'.

Comment: Yeah, I think I got it. Changed the answer. Take a look at the `owned_not_delegated_warehouses` association, the`warehouses_under_responsibility` method and the Note section.